# Use regex_replace to extract all value in json array and remove value after separate

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to extract all ids from json array in snowflake before ':'

I have this json format for example: {   "198002": 2115960,   "198006": 604560,   "320906": 302280 }

I have tried something like this:
`select player_army_load ,trim(regexp_replace(player_army_load,'\:.*$',''),'{|"')  as element_id  from x` 
but this extract only first value, but I want 198002,198006,320906

extract all value before ":"

Answer (score 2):

I see you need to extract keys from the json, in this case you can use [`OBJECT_KEYS`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_keys):

```
select OBJECT_KEYS(PARSE_JSON(col1))
from jsontable;
```

Result :

```
[   "198002",   "198006",   "320906" ]
```

And if you want to get your result as a string then use `ARRAY_TO_STRING` :

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING( OBJECT_KEYS(PARSE_JSON(col1)), ',' )
FROM jsontable;
```

Result :

```
198002,198006,320906
```

Comment: Glad to hear :) Can you accept it if you see it helpful

Answer (score 0):

this is for you try for loop in your object

```
const data = {1:"one",2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four"}

for(const i in data){
  **perform your task with i**
}
```